# How to redirect external web request to localhost's testing server

Tags: redirect, request

Some web services calls my web application(www.myapplication.com/external_update_handler).
I need to test those requests locally, so I'd like to know your opinions about how can I "redirect" those requests to my localhost dev machine(that is outside of my web aplication domain) so I can debug.
Probably it's needed a service/server to get those external requests and a desktop application that sends it to localhost:5555/external_update_handler, but I have no idea where to start and simpler options.

Comment: You didn't tell us what server do you use / in general you need to setup reverse proxy. In case your dev machine is accessible from the server, the setup it simple... can be more specific on apache setup

Answer (score 1):

Either update your code to hit the local version of www.myapplication.com/external_update_handler on the URL/Host it is accessible on, or you can configure the machine running the web service (the ones making the outbound calls to your web application) and configure a hosts file http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) to force the machine looking up your web app to resolve the domain to a different IP, likely the one that resolves to your local environment,.